# Find totals for weektodate,monthtodate from sql server tables

Tags: sql-server

[image]

I'm trying to get total number of applications made for current day (Monday) to (Last Monday) , and Tuesday to Last week Tuesday and so on. Also, I would like to get applications made for this Month (Month to date  ). Please help

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

```
Category    Date    Day     Applications
CASS    16/09/2019  Monday  1
CASS    16/09/2019  Monday  3
RBS     16/09/2019  Monday  1
RBS     16/09/2019  Monday  3
RBS     16/09/2019  Monday  14
RBS     16/09/2019  Monday  15
CASS    23/09/2019  Monday  2
CASS    23/09/2019  Monday  1
CASS    23/09/2019  Monday  2
CASS    23/09/2019  Monday  1
CASS    23/09/2019  Monday  8
RBS     23/09/2019  Monday  3
RBS     23/09/2019  Monday  3
```

Output:

```
               23/09/2019
```

CASS:                    14
Previous week:         14-4=10

RBS:                     6
Previous week:           6-33= -27

Month to date(Total aplications till date): 57

Comment: Can you put output columns and rows expected?

Comment: CASS: 14 Previous week : 14-4=10

RBS: 6 Previous week: 6-33= -27

Month to date(Total aplications till date): 57

Comment: @SindhuB just repeating a non-formatted pile of text is not making it clear what you want as output.

Comment: I'm not sure how to format, Can you help me with that please?

Comment: I don't know what you want as output. Is this 4 columns? or Rows? or???

Comment: I have attached picture how I want the output format to be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `LEAD()` function you could achieve what you looking for, have a look at following example, you may want adjust `PARTITION BY` clause and sub-query as per your requirements:

[Query Result..](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f16f758e860329a63d4d62aeab6bd114)

```
SELECT  T.*, 
        LEAD (AppCount) OVER (PARTITION BY cDay ORDER BY weekNum) as PrevAppCount,
        T.AppCount - LEAD (AppCount) OVER (PARTITION BY cDay ORDER BY weekNum) 
FROM    (
        select  Category, 
                datepart(week,cDate) as weekNum,
                cDay,
                sum (AppCount) as AppCount
        from MyTable
        Group by Category, Datepart(week,cDate),cDay
        ) AS T
```

Comment: LEAD Function available only from SQL Server 2012, but I'm using SQL 2008 R2, thank you

Comment: Hi @SindhuB, i miss that from your OP, in that case you got a option to make [self JOIN of sub-query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=009491c4d8a8a15027d97863cdcf5926)

Answer (score 0):

You can write query like this:

```
;with cte as (
select *, rown = ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by category order by [Date]) from (
    select category, [Date], sum(applications) appcnt from #table 
        group by category, [Date]
    ) t
)
Select  case when nextweek.Category is null then curweek.Category else 
 curweek.Category + ' Previous week' end , 
    case when nextweek.Category is not null then nextweek.appcnt - curweek.appcnt   else curweek.appcnt end
    from cte curweek 
  left join cte nextweek on curweek.rown = nextweek.rown -1
    and curweek.Category = nextweek.Category
union all
  select 'Month to date', sum(applications) from #table
```

code:

https://rextester.com/ABI84558